# Add a formatting rule for a text in a form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-form, form

Is there any way of creating a formatting rule for a title or text?
I want to make a text appear when I set true a checkbox. I know how to do it with a texbox but not with plain text.
Thank you in advance.